# Is Google maps `region` parameter determined automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The Google Maps JS API allows for a few localization options to be set, some appear to be automatically detected by the users browser, for example the `language` parameter will be set by the client.

There seems to be no mention of the `region` parameter being set in the same fashion, however it affects the user experience and how the maps handle user input.

Do I need to set this parameter to provide a more localized experience for visitors?

This is not clear from the docs, or my testing (what is the best way to really test this?)

Here is an example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-region-us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps JavaScript API supports both language and region parameters. You can apply them when you load an API as described in the official documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

Typically providing a region parameter affects the representation of tile imagery especially in areas where different countries have different names for the same geographical feature. For example, [Sea of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_of_Japan_naming_dispute) which will be shown as East see with Korean regional settings.

Referring to the services (geocoding, directions, etc.) Google Maps JavaScript API uses a visible view port of the map to bias results to the visible area/region. This logic is applied to client side services and places library as you can see in the example mentioned in your question.

I believe the easiest way to demonstrate this might be autocomplete in [place finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder). Let set visible view port on Sydney and type 'Hyde'. All prediction will be from Australia according to the visible view port as shown in my screenshot.

[image]

Now change view port to London and type 'Hyde' again. This time all predictions will be biased toward United Kingdom.

[image]

I hope my answer explains your doubts!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, great. My question is mainly, if I know my users region, _should_ I add that parameter for google maps? or should I just let it just do what it would automatically?

Comment: region parameter makes sense for certain countries where local law requires certain representation of disputed areas. For example, if your users are from India by default disputed areas will be outside of the country border, but local law requires to show disputed areas as a part of India, so adding the region parameter you can solve this issue.

Comment: So should I add it? Would it provide a better or more specific than leaving it out?

Comment: Depends on your use case. If you care about representation of tiles according to local laws of each region use a region parameter, otherwise it's not necessary.

Comment: This is not my question, my question is about the automatic detection of the region. Is it better that I apply a region if I know it (IE from my database). I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding my question. If for example, I put IN rather than CN, and the person was actually in CN, would it not have been better to leave it off and let the automatic behavior work. When would I WANT to put the region param?